# i3bar covers Photoshop menu

Tags: photoshop, wine

I run the i3wm with the i3bar.I installed Photoshop CS6 through Wine.

I have found a few quirks:

- the i3bar is overlapping the Photoshop's Menu bar (File, etc): [image: i3wm and Photoshop]
- resizing the Photoshop window (i.e. by placing it into floating mode or opening another application side by side) does not re-scale photoshop, instead the app just covers half of the Photoshop window.

I assume these issues are related; yet the first one is more important. What would fix this issue?

Comment: You could fix it by turning on the wine virtual desktop, which runs windows programs inside a window. The i3bar would not overlap this window. Run winecfg, go to the Graphics tab, and check "Emulate a virtual desktop."

Comment: @tbodt Thank so much for the tip. You solution was already a great improvement, but it requires setting the correct desktop size, and is not flexible regarding resizing the Photoshop window.
Just above that option I have unchecked "Allow the window manager to decorate the windows" and now it works great!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution is to dissalow the window manager to decorate the window.

This can be done by running `winecfg`, go to the `Graphics` tab and uncheck `Allow the window manager to decorate the windows`.

This resolves both issue I noted in the question: the i3bar covering the menu, and the resizing quirks when Photoshop does not fill the entire screen.